# Choosing maximum from multiple columns with index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-cleaning

I have a dataframe

```
product     Jan     Feb     March   April
Apple       10      21      8       7
Banana      9       9       11      8
Orange      20      6       4       8
```

For each given product, I want to know the max amount with it's respective month.

```
product     Month   Value       
Apple       Feb     21      
Banana      March   11
Orange      Jan     20
```

if there any way to do this without explicitly going through each row.

Answer (score 2):

First remove column `product` for [`assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) new columns created by [`max`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.max.html) and [`idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html):

```
a = df.drop('product', axis=1)
df =  df[['product']].assign(Month=a.idxmax(axis=1), Value=a.max(axis=1))
print (df)
  product  Month  Value
0   Apple    Feb     21
1  Banana  March     11
2  Orange    Jan     20
```

Comment: You are so fast I came with two line answer you already posted answer with assign :(

Comment: Yes, assign here is better ;)

Answer (score 1):

Here is one of the solution without `groupby`

```
df.melt('product').sort_values('value').drop_duplicates(['product'],keep='last')
Out[307]: 
  product variable  value
7  Banana    March     11
2  Orange      Jan     20
3   Apple      Feb     21
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df = df.set_index('product')     
df.apply( lambda x: pd.Series([x.max(), x.idxmax()], index=['Month','Value']), axis=1).reset_index()
```

output

```
  product  Month  Value
0   Apple     21    Feb
1  Banana     11  March
2  Orange     20    Jan
```

if you want to assign the values back

```
 df[['Month', 'Value']] = df.apply( lambda x: pd.Series([x.max(), x.idxmax()]), axis=1)

 print df.reset_index()

    product  Jan  Feb  March  April  Month  Value
0   Apple   10   21      8      7     21    Feb
1  Banana    9    9     11      8     11  March
2  Orange   20    6      4      8     20    Jan
```